# Is there a way to replace richfaces tag "<a:queue" to primefaces and JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I need to migrate my legacy application using JSF 1.2/SEAM to JSF 2.2.

I need to replace the following code in one of the template files

```html
<a:queue name="ic" requestDelay="250"/>
```

Please suggest a replacement for this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you are migrating to PrimeFaces, you can simply use [`p:ajax`](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/ajaxbehavior) with the `delay` attribute.

From the documentation:

> If less than delay milliseconds elapses between calls to request() only the most recent one is sent and all other requests are discarded. If this option is not specified, or if the value of delay is the literal string 'none' without the quotes, no delay is used.